# are the token generated by byte stream decoder passed to preparser or parser?

Tags: javascript, v8

I was studying about the v8 engine to be specific. I came across parser and preparser.
The byte streams that are generated from the byte stream decoder decodes it into tokens.

***is the tokens sent to preparser or parser?***
***also, since preparser does not create AST, will it create it later when we call a function that was skipped and not compiled?***

i went through the net and v8 offical docs and i find it difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The preparser is used first (hence the "pre-" in its name).

The parser is used when an AST is required, which is the case when the function gets compiled (lazily or eagerly).

All of this is an optimization; the details can and do change over time. A JavaScript engine, in general, doesn't need a preparser. It could compile all functions eagerly. Or even if it wants to compile functions lazily, it could use the full parser for its preparsing needs, and simply discard the AST that's produced. Having a separate preparser that does less work allows it to be faster than the full parser.